# Remove old Office Tenant from Browser

Tags: microsoft-office

I used to work for a client who provided me with an Office account. Whenever I would log into this account, the client's logo would already show in the login screen. (Don't know why this would be useful but anyway...)

Now I'm not working for the old client anymore but for a new one instead who has also provided me with an account. When I'm trying to log into Teams, it shows me the login screen of the old client and won't let me log in. It only works on Firefox instead of Chrome, because I've only signed into the old client's Office tenant with Chrome. How can I sign into the new tenant with Chrome and let Chrome forget the old client?

Comment: I've just made it work by clearing all browsing data. However, this can't be the preferred solution as I would have liked to keep my browsing data.

Comment: Please go to Settings > Accounts > Email & Account and Access work or school, please make sure the old account is removed.

Comment: Which settings exactly? I can't find an "account" section in the Chrome settings...